# Kubectl set environment variables and run command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a container running on Kubernetes where I would like to run a command from my local terminal. The working directory of the container based on its yaml file is at say `/opt/gopath/src/a/`. However, I would like to run the command at directory `/opt/gopath/src/b/`. Additionally, I also need to set certain temporary environment variables before running this command. So currently, this is what I am doing:

`kubectl exec $pod_name -- bash -c "cd ../b/; env ENV_VARIABLE_1=ENV_VALUE_2 && env ENV_VARIABLE_2=ENV_VALUE_2 && <cmd to run>".`

This seems to be working currently. However, I am not convinced that this is the best way to achieve this. Also, running this command displays all the environment variables in the container -- which I would like not to be printed if possible. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think this would work - the `env` command sets env vars, but when it exits the vars are lost.  Hence it must run the command directly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128939/) which uses `env` correctly.

Answer (score 16):

In case of static variables, I would suggest using [Config maps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-pod-environment-variables-using-configmap-data).

Since you need to use temporary variables from a local shell, there is no need to use long and complicated commands as exec connects your terminal to the running Container (pod). I tested your issue and created a simple environment variable on the local system. I used syntax provided by you:

```
kubectl exec -it $pod_name -- sh -c 'key=123 key2=121; echo "$key $key2"'
```

To pass env vars, you can just set it like that and add delimiter ';' between variables and your command.

Comment: I am using the ```env``` field to declare static environment variables. However, in this particular case, I need to change one of those variables temporarily to be able to run the command. I haven't had to use Config Maps but I might look into them. Seems like your command looks slightly compared to mine. Thanks!

Comment: This temporary env var command is close but doesn't actually set environment variables, but local vars that the shell substitutes in the echo command.  You would need to do `kubectl exec -it $pod_name -- sh -c 'export key=123 key2=121;  mycommand'` to enable `mycommand` to see the env var settings.  (Or just use the `env` command to set vars and run the command, as in other answers).

Answer (score 3):

This is very late but I'm sure it will be very helpful.

`envsubst` solves this issue in a one-liner.

The below command replaces env variables in YAML file with actual values.

```
cat <filename>.yaml | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: envsubst is a part of gettext

Comment: without cat: `envsubst < config.yml | kubectl apply -f -`

Answer (score 2):

`bash -c "cd ../b/; env ENV_VARIABLE_1=ENV_VALUE_2 ENV_VARIABLE_2=ENV_VALUE_2 <cmd to run>"`

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest specifying the details (including env variables) in a manifest .yaml file and then doing `kubectl create -f manifest.yaml`

This is much more reproducible than having a ton of flags in the command line.