# Kubectl exec command fails due to 'No such file or directory'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run a kubectl exec command on a pod, but it fails  saying *'No such file or directory'*

I can run the command if I login to the terminal of the pod through bash
Also this problem is only for a few commands.
I found that there is a PATH variable difference

1. When i do kubectl exec $POD -- printenv  , then
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2. When i run -- printenv from the terminal of POD  , then
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/abc/scripts:/opt/abc/bin:/opt/admin/bin:/opt/abc/bin:/root/bin

I am guessing this is causing the commands to fails when run through kubectl exec.

Any ideas to overcome this are welcome; can we pass the env variable of PATH in someway to the POD which using kubectl exec ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try executing `bash -c "<command>"`

```
$ kubectl exec <pod> -- bash -c "<cmd>"
```

It is likely PATH is being modified by some shell initialization files

Comment: Tried that already, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was required env variable (PATH) and some others were missing.
I passed the required env variables along with the command.

Example

*kubectl exec $pod_name -- bash -c "cd ../b/; env ENV_VARIABLE_1=ENV_VALUE_2 && env ENV_VARIABLE_2=ENV_VALUE_2 && "*

Details: -
[Kubectl set environment variables and run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128480/kubectl-set-environment-variables-and-run-command/51128939#51128939)